# Example of a space which is countable, connected and not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking for an example of topological space which is countable, connected and not compact. Everything that I thought of so far (which were mostly subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$) was lacking some of these properties. For example as soon as I take something with discrete topology, the space won't be connected anymore. If I take something with indescrete topology, then the space will be compact. So I assume I should take something more exotic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy example is $\mathbb N$ with topology
$$
\tau = \{ \mathbb N, \emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0, 1, 2\}, \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, \ldots
\}.
$$
This is $T_0$ space which is connected, because if $U, V$ are open and $ \mathbb N = U \cup V$ then $U = \mathbb N \lor V = \mathbb N$. So if the sum was disjoint, then one of the sets would have to be empty. It's not compact, since
$$
\{\{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0, 1, 2\}, \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, \ldots
\}
$$
does not have finite subcover.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another example is $\mathbb N$ with the special topology for $n_0$,
$$
\tau = \{ U\subset\mathbb N\,|\, n_0\in U
\}\cup{\emptyset}
$$
where $n_0\in\Bbb N$ is a fixed natural number. Since all open sets except the empty set contain $n_0$, any two non-trivial open sets can not be disjoint. Hence, $(\Bbb N,\tau)$ is connected.

The open cover $\cal F=\{\{n_0,x\}\,|\,x\in\Bbb N, x\neq n_0\}$ has no finite subcover. Hence, $(\Bbb N,\tau)$ is not compact.